# How to loop google-Apps script?

Tags: api, google-apps-script, youtube-api

I would like to gather subscribers for the channel id of youtube with an app script on Google Spreadsheets. But it only worked with one id.

I'd like to use a repeat statement, but I can't because I'm not good enough. I'd appreciate it if you could help me.

```
function getChannelInfo() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var channel = ss.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var data = YouTube.Channels.list('statistics', {id: channel});
  var item = data.items[0];
  var info = [item.statistics.subscriberCount];
  ss.getRange("C2").setValues([info]);
}
```

I want to gather subscribers for all video IDs in column B, but only one comes out. Help me.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ks_tE9uDdOcTKML8jf_40lJpcImMoh-JYivpV38zpCk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

No problem

1. In this statement `var channel = ss.getRange("B2").getValue();`, you are calling just one value. Instead you should go with an array of values. Like `ss.getrange(row, colum, number of rows).getdisplayvalues();`
2. use FOR LOOP to run for each value in the above array and set values in the Spreadsheet in the corressponding cells.

Let me know if you need help :)